# Which principle goes against the concept of Bohr's fixed orbits?

Tags: atomic-structure

Can you also state the principle which goes against it?

Comment: We don't really think in terms of principles.

Answer (score 5):

One principle that goes against the fixed orbit concept is the Heisenberg Uncertainty Principle.  Bohr's fixed orbits imply precise knowledge of radial position (the radius of the orbit) and also precise knowledge of the radial momentum (zero), violating the principle for the radial component of position and motion.